# mysql() refuses to read characters in php

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

I copied some code from word into my database which is causing problems when I want to retrieve them with mysql() in php. I've identified what the problem is, dashes like this one is causing an error retrieving it:

```
Tue – Thur:
```

I have to convert the dash to the following one in order for mysql() to be able to retrieve it: (it's almost unnoticeable but it causes an error that took me some time to figure out what was happening)

```
Tue - Thur:
```

This is also causing an error:

```
it’s
```

but not this one:

```
it's
```

This one is causing also a problem:

```
course…much more!
```

I have to change it to this one:

```
course...much more
```

Because sometimes I had to copy huge amounts of text into the database is hard for me to spot which part of the text is causing the problem. Sometimes it looks almost identical.
So, my question is, does anybody knows a tool or something that I can use to paste the text and it could help me either point me to where the problematic characters are or change them to the ones that won't cause a problem?

**Note**

Now I know that in order to fix this I have to change the encoding of the string that I'm inserting into the database from Unicode to UTF8. Is there any idea how I can get that string converted?

Comment: What's the encoding of your mysql table?

Comment: Do you use something like `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`?

Comment: What errors are you getting when you retrieve them? Show your PHP code.

Comment: Well, in the first place I didn't provide the php code because that's irrelevant for me since I'm not going to change the code. I just want to know if there's a way to identify those weird characters so when I face this in the future I know how to fix it.

Comment: How are you storing in database? How are you retrieving? What error is what causing? Your question lacks a real question

Comment: Indeed, you should attempt to fix the problem and store these characters transparently instead of trying to get rid of them. Difficult to say what the problem is without an actual error, but generally you need to “UTF-8 all the way through” and that typically includes using `mysql_set_charset` (in preference to problematic `SET NAMES`).

Comment: @Onimusha All those answers don't matter because I'm not planning to change the code, the way I'm storing things in the database or anything else. I know what the problem is and I know what is causing it. I just need to have a way to convert Unicode to UTF8 so I can store them and don't have any problems with it.

Comment: @bobince I was wondering why the error message would matter here if all I need is to convert Unicode to UTF8. I'm not using mysql_set_charset because I'm not planning to change the code in any way. What I want to change though is the format of encoding that I'm using for those values in the database.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you get when trying to read `Tue – Thur:` -- perhaps `Tue ` (truncation), perhaps `Tue ?? Thur:` (question marks); `Tue � Thur:`; `Tue â€“ Thur:`; perhaps something else??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert this Unicode string to utf8 I discovered a php function `utf8_decode` which after you pass the string with the unicode characters, any weird character will be set to "?" So I can identify them easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting into notepad, then recopy out again before pasting into your database.

Also what is the encoding on the html page?

`<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

may help

Comment: If you save as *.txt from word, you can choose what encoding to use, one option is utf8

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with mysql or the problem